# how to create a global variable for every entrance to the website?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have global array that works just fine and stores the URL's of the chosen images from the user after i click submit in the form.

the problem is when i want to submit another form, the global array will still have the URL's of the previous submission.

what i want to do is to create an array for every user to store his URL's, one he click submit, the array will be dropped or deleted. so if there were multiple users using the same function, every one of them will have his own array to store his URL's

How do i do this?

this is what i have tried but when i click on submit on the form page, nothing happens

first, this is the method that returns the url of the chosen image by the user, the method exists in both folder (both/file.js)

```
storeUrlInDatabaseSS: function( url ) {
    check( url, String );
    Modules.both.checkUrlValidity( url );

    try {
      return url;
     } catch( exception ) {
      return exception;
    }
  }
```

then i created the session variables in the client side (client/file.js)

```
Session.set("screenshots", []);
Session.set("i", 0);

var screenshots = Session.get("screenshots");
var i = Session.get("i");
```

and here i store the url in the array

```
let _addUrlToDatabaseSS = ( url ) => {
  screenshots[i++] = url;
  Session.set("screenshots", screenshots);
};
```

and am using [Meteor Collection Hook Package](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks)

and i added these two lines of code which should be excited after the user press submit, they exist inside "client/files.js" directory

```
Products.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.screenShots = Session.get("screenshots");
});
```

now whenever i click submit nothing happens, i think the problem is because nothing is actually stored inside the screenShots attribute in the collection here

```
  screenShots: {
    type: [String]
  },
```

when i set the screenShots attribute to an empty array by default like the code below, the submit button works

```
  screenShots: {
    type: [String],
    autoValue: function() {
      return [];
    }
  },
```

I tried to use the other way of using AutoForm.hooks

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    submitPostForm: {
        before: {
            insert: function(doc) {
                doc.$set.screenShots = Session.get("screenshots");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

the is my form in the .html file

```
{{> quickForm collection="Products" id="submitPostForm"
  type="method" meteormethod="submitPost" omitFields="createdAt, previewImage, screenShots, sourceCode, userID"}}
```

and this is the method triggered once the user submit the form, it exist in the server side.

```
submitPost: function (app) {
    // Console.log('new App:', app);
    check(app, {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        category: String,
        price: Number
    });
    Products.insert(app);
}
```

for some reason my before hook isn't working and i can't see why!
what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, it seems to me that you are looking for collections but your question is not quite understandable. Please rewrite what you are looking for and not what you have tried already.

Comment: Why not use `Session` to store user-specific information? Even a global array declared on client side will be unique to each user. So what is your question exactly?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen can i use Session to create a global array specifically for each user? if yes please can you show me how? because this is what am looking for actually

Comment: @TomFreudenberg I want to create global array specifically for each user, because my array now is for the whole system. i will modify the question

Comment: Modify the question in a way what kind of solution you are looking for: e.g. "every user should be able to upload and describe screenshots based on urls" or something descriptive.

Comment: @TomFreudenberg i just modified it more, hope its clear now, if not let me know to further modify it

Comment: If you run multiple instances of your app on separate servers, why not using environment variables and access them via Node-native `process.env` plain-object that works in Meteor, too?

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin i didn't understand what u said, but am testing my app on one server,

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin can you provide me a link of what you said please, i want to check it out

Comment: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to create a global array per user is to use `Session`. This way it is also possible to *persist* the data across the app (only client-side).

Simple way to use `Session` is thus:

1. Create an array in `Session` called `url_list`:

   `Session.set("url_list", []);`
2. Retrieve the array from `Session`:

   `var url_list = Session.get("url_list");`
3. Make changes to `url_list`:

   `url_list.push(someData);`
4. Store `url_list` in the `Session` again:

   `Session.set("url_list", url_list);`

**Note**: `Session` can only be used on client-side and all related code should be on the client-side.

[More about Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session).

**PERSISTING DATA TO SERVER-SIDE**:

The best way to persist the `url_list` to the server, would be to insert a new document into the database collection containing the `Session` data.

```
insertToDB = function() {

    var url_list = Session.get('url_list');
    Products.insert({
        'url_list': url_list
    });
    Session.set('url_list', []); // To empty the client-side list

}
```

Comment: are there a way to do it on code that runs on both the client and the server as well?, because am using the global array on code that runs on both the client and the server (both directory)

Comment: because am returning the value of the Session variable inside my collection, and am using the collection in my server side, so i need it to be available on both client and server, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Your question did not reflect that the code is meant to run on client and server both. So I assumed that it is meant for client. `Session` is only client side. So we'll have to find another way to tackle it. Will update my answer.

Comment: yes i should have mentioned it, am new to meteor and just dived in so i didn't know about sessions. I found a solution that am trying to implement, will post it here if it worked, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Alright, try your solution. If you get stuck, we are here to help.

Comment: Thanks :) , the solution didn't work  -_- i edited my question with the solution i have tried

Comment: Check my updated answer. There is no need to use `hooks` for this purpose. And I am not sure if it's a good idea to use block-scoped `let` for adding URL to `Session` data. I've given a simple way to do all that and I've tested it too.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, the reason i needed to use the hook because i will only store the array in the document once the user finish uploading all the images, and the amount of the uploaded images is up to the user. therefore i will only store the array in the collection once he click submit, are there other way, maybe you meant to do it in certain way, if so could you please elaborate further because i didn't get it on when will i use insertToDB in my code

Comment: because the only way i can know the user finish uploading the images is when he clicks submit, or the other way is to update the "screenShots" element inside the document every time the user uploaded an image

Comment: Simply call `insertToDB` when the user submits the form. You can also call it in the hook itself.

Comment: When user uploads an image, update the `Session` data. When the user submits the form, call `insertToDB`.

Comment: i updated my question to elaborate what happen in my code once the user click on submit, is it still possible to use the method? because if am not mistaken, since the method on the server, i can't use the Session variable.

Comment: currently am trying to use the meteor methods and pass the value through the argument in Meteor.call. if there is a way that i didn't get it yet to implement your solution, please let me know, thanks again for the help u provided and sorry for taking your time -_-

Comment: There should not be any problems due to meteor methods. Please check in your console if URLs are getting stored properly in your `Session` variable.

Comment: Also do you intend to insert into database directly or via meteor methods?

Comment: yea they are stored then i checked from the console, currently am trying using meteor methods, i opened new question for updating the document in the collection :)

Comment: i accepted your answer since its correct in inserting new document in the collection, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad to help. Also, checking your new question.

Comment: this is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840617/how-to-access-and-change-a-specific-attribute-in-a-collection