# How to access and change a specific attribute in a collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I have a collection called "Products". I want to access and change an attribute called "screenShots" inside the collection.

This code didn't work with me

```
screenshotsURLS: function(sshots) {
    check(sshots, [String]);
    Products.update({},{$set:{screenShots:sshots}});
    console.log(sshots);
}
```

when i console.log the sshots, i can see that the array exists, but the update function isn't working

how do i set the screenShots attribute inside the Product collection to whatever value passed in "screenshotsURLS" function?

Comment: Do you want to update all the docs at once?

Comment: @Blaze Sahlzen no, only that specific element "screenShots" in the current doc

Comment: Your current code will update the very first document it finds in the collection. You should specify a query in the first `{}`, such as `{_id: someId}`.

Comment: Is your example code located on server-side or client-side? Is it a `Meteor method`?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen the id of the document you mean? and how do i get it? the code is in the client side, i passed the value from the Session (i used the way you told me) to the server side, and yea it is a Meteor method

Comment: 1. The meteor method should be located in the `lib/` folder (accessible by both client and server), otherwise the server-side database won't be updated. 2. You should call the method from your client-side code (this is where `Session` is accessible). 3. Usually ID of the document to be updated can be found by doing `find`/`findOne` operation, **or** is already known. It's down to a matter of how you've designed your program.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen thanks i will try your solution now, just one question, i have folder called both that is accessible by both client and server, so i should create new folder called "lib" inside both folder? or outside? and is it going to be "lib/methods.js" or "both/lib/methods.js"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105586/discussion-between-blaze-sahlzen-and-behrouz-riahi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to update the mongodb document.

THis is how you can update the doc in meteor.

```
collectionName.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)
```

In your your case collectionName is Products and field is screenShots.
So for doing this. Your query will be 
sshots

```
Products.update({},{$set:{screenShots:sshots}}) (Be careful this will update all of your doc)
```

For selecting doc update use the query like.

```
Products.update({name:'yourProductName'},{$set:{screenShots:sshots}})
```

For more about update a please check this [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Comment: is it possible to only change the screenShots attribute without changing the value if the other attributes?

Comment: i mean if i used Products.update({},{$set:{screenShots:sshots}}) will it change the value of the other elements in the collection?

Comment: No, Products.update({},{$set:{screenShots:sshots}}) will only change the value of screenShots field.

Comment: If you want to change more filed just add those filed like Products.update({},{$set:{field1 : value1 , field2: value2 : ...}})

Comment: i updated my question after implementing your solution, still didn't work with me, am i missing something?

Comment: May I know did you remove autopublish  and insecure, If yes then where you are calling this function client side or server side ?

Comment: yes i did, the function is inside "lib" directory, i can update other values of the document that are not of array type, i believe the solution might be because i gave the screenShot element an autoValue, how do i give it a default value? i know how to give a default value to String type elements but not arrays

Comment: if you know how i can do it with an array type element it might work,

Comment: i accepted your answer, because i manage to update other values with your solution, so it does work, the problem has to do with something else, i asked new question if you can check it out please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864738/how-to-set-a-default-value-to-element-in-a-collection-of-type-string